# optimising algorithm for counting number of pairs in array such that A[i]*A[j] is not a perfect square

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures

Given an array count the total number of pairs of (i,j) such that A[i]*A[j] is not a perfect square.

```
input
n=3
input array={2,3,12}
output:2
```

explanation 2 * 3 i.e `A[0]*A[1]` & 2 * 12 i.e `A[0]*A[2]` does form perfect square. **pair 2 * 3 & 3 * 2 are counted as a single pair.**
`my approach & code:`
i simply run 2 for loop which gives result in quardratic time. How can i optimise it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
bool isPerfectSquare(long long x)
{
    if (x >= 0) {
 
        long long sr = sqrt(x);
        return (sr * sr == x);
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    long long t;cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        long long n;cin>>n;
        vector<long long>v(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>v[i];
        }
        long long count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                    if(!isPerfectSquare(v[i]*v[j])){
                        count++;
                    }
            }
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't an SO type of question. You'd better do your homework elsewhere. I can give you a tip: figure out what are the conditions for a pair to form a perfect square and simplify it. Then it won't difficult to write code that takes `O(n)` or `O(n lon n)` operations.

Comment: @ALX23z I am dying to see `O(n)` solution. I am also very interested in `O(n log n)` solution with a reasonable space complexity.

Comment: @user58697 you can find a mapping function`F` with property: `F(x) == F(y)` if and only if `xy` is a perfect square. Computing `F(x)` might be a bit heavy but it is technically `O(1)`. I won't tell what `F` is but it is not hard to come up with. Compute  `F` of every element and you just need to figure out which elements and how many of them are duplicated. To do so use hash tables techniques (`unordered_map`) for `O(n)` (typical) or sort the array for `O(n log n)` (maximum).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to take out all the square factors first, which you can trivially do by testing divisibility by all numbers up to sqrt(A[i])).  Then only matching pairs produce perfect square products:

[2,3,12] -> [2,3,3]

You can determine the number of square pairs by counting the frequency of each value, and then subtract that from the total number of pairs.