# How to solve problems in the form count the number of pairs a[i], a[j] from vector a such that a[i]+a[j] fulfill some condition?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, time

I practice CodeSignal exercices in C++ and I have to solve problems like the following:

There is (always) a non-empty vector named "a" containing int:

```
vector<int> a;
```

count the number of pairs a[i], a[j] where (i != j) such that a[i]+a[j] = k (k is given)

or

count the number of pairs a[i], a[j] with (i < j)such that a[i]+a[j] are divisible by a number m (m is given)

or

count the number of pairs a[i], a[j] with (i < j)such that a[i]*a[j] form a perfect square

or

count the number of pairs a[i], a[j] with (i < j) such that a[i]+a[j] == some power of 2

(for this one, I already figure out the ((n & (n-1)) == 0) condition.)

and so on

I can solve all of these problems, but they take too long to run and I end up exceeding the time limit. I always go through the vector a by using 2 loops in the following way:

```
int count(0);
for(int i(0); i < a.size(); ++i)
{
for(int j(0 or i); j < a.size(); ++j)
{
if(i != j)
{ if((a[i] + a[j]) % m == 0)
{count = count + 1;} }
}
}

return count;
```

Is there a general way of making this more efficient?

Or should I adapt to every exercise (and in that case, there is an individual trick for every exercise?)

Are there general principles for solving this type of problems?

I also checked the answer for [optimising algorithm for counting number of pairs in array such that A[i]*A[j] is not a perfect square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793507/optimising-algorithm-for-counting-number-of-pairs-in-array-such-that-aiaj-i), but I don't understand it. sqrt(A[i]) where A[i] is the max or the normal one?

Comment: It depends on the condition. If there is no mathematical trick you can use to speed up things, then you are out of luck.

Comment: So such problems always depend on the condition entered?

Comment: Sorting the numbers can help, certainly would with the first example. Second example I would place the numbers in buckets depending on what their value mod m is. Then you can easily find all the pairs.

Comment: Is the pair `<a[i], a[i]>` allowed, (when the indices are the same for both pair elements)?  This would make the loops simpler.

Comment: Often there are operations that help you to reduce the number of solutions to consider. E.g. if you need to find the number of pairs such that the sum is equal to a specific number, you could simply sort and then iterate through the collection using 2 iterators moving in oposite directions through the collection. For "sum is divisible by `m`" problem a different approach is required though, e.g. group the elements by their values modulo `m`...

Comment: What about finding perfect squares? I do not fully understand the solution offered in the link...

Comment: The whole point of these puzzles is for you to find the algorithmic trick that avoids having to brute force it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I understand that it seems to depend on the problems, it always give me a few ways to understand and solve these issues.

Comment: @john What would be the algorithmic trick for a perfect square problem?

Comment: I also had a problem which I could not solve, which requires counting the pairs such that a[i]*a[j] == some power of 2. I found the ((n & n-1) == 0) trick but I could not figure out how to go through the loop without iterating through each of them.

Comment: Could you help find a few more ways in solving these problems (perfect square and power of 2)?

Comment: @bakeseg Not sure, nothing suggests itself immediately

Comment: @john In the case of the power of 2, it is numbers added. I made a mistake in my comment, I corrected it.

Comment: @bakeseg OK that changes things, add that one to the I'm not sure list.

Comment: I used a throwaway for posting this question (and I did not keep the password). I might reconnect to my old account next time you see me.

Comment: Yes definitely.

Comment: @bakeseg _"I used a throwaway for posting this question ..."_ Don't do such things, you'll get in danger to be completely banned from this site with all your accounts. Tempted to send a flag for  moderator attention regarding this!

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but the solution I provide will need modification if you are not using integers.

In fact, using the O(n^2) approach that you provide is slow. You always need to reduce the number of computations you do by using appropriate date structures.
For this algorithm, for a value `a` we are trying to find a value `b` such that `a + b = 2` (for example).
We can use a for loop to loop through all the values, and at each iteration save the necessary `b` value to make `a + b = 2` true. In this case: `b = 2 -a`
In other words, you need to solve for `b`.

**Definitions:**

- Let a function `condition(a,b)`, be the condition for a valid pair with input `a`, `b`.
- Let a function `inverse(a)`, be the function such that `b = inverse(a)`

To store the previous computations we will use a hash map, so these are the headers for our c++ file.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
```

This will be our main function to find a `std::pair` (you might need to change the variables names like 'map' that may conflict with your surrounding code):

```cpp
// Find a pair of numbers in a vector that satisfy a given condition
std::pair<int, int> findPair(std::vector<int>& nums, std::function<bool(int, int)> condition, std::function<int(int)> inverse)
{
    // Create an empty unordered_map
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        // Check if the condition is satisfied with any previously saved result
        // use the inverse function provided to determine if it's a valid pair
        int valid = inverse(nums[i]);
        if (map.find(valid) != map.end())
            return std::pair<int, int> (nums[i], valid);

        // insert this number into the map
        map[nums[i]] = i;
    }

    // No pair found ...
    return std::pair<int, int> (-1, -1);
}
```

**Example:**

```cpp
// Define the numbers
std::vector<int> nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

// Find the pair
std::pair<int, int> p = findPair(
    nums, 
    [](int a, int b) // Condition
    {
        return a*b == 20;
    },
    [](int a) // Inverse (solution for b variable)
    {
        return 20/a;
    }
);
```

`Output: 5, 4`

Comment: Does this solve your question?